# php /c# hash password

Tags: php, objective-c

i have a app that is in the app store, and i use this to hash the pass:

```
    //salt the password
NSString* saltedPassword = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", fldPassword.text, kSalt];

//prepare the hashed storage
NSString* hashedPassword = nil;
unsigned char hashedPasswordData[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
//hash the pass
NSData *data = [saltedPassword dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if (CC_SHA1([data bytes], [data length], hashedPasswordData)) {
    hashedPassword = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:hashedPasswordData length:sizeof(hashedPasswordData) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

my password in the database is Vîÿ¿ Ø2(&Zw6

my problem is that i cant find a php function that dos the same, so users can reset there pass  .

i can do it like this in Xcode:

```
 NSString *hashkey = <your data here>;
 // PHP uses ASCII encoding, not UTF
 const char *s = [hashkey cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
 NSData *keyData = [NSData dataWithBytes:s length:strlen(s)];

 // This is the destination
uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};
// This one function does an unkeyed SHA1 hash of your hash data
CC_SHA1(keyData.bytes, keyData.length, digest);

// Now convert to NSData structure to make it usable again
NSData *out = [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
// description converts to hex but puts <> around it and spaces every 4 bytes
NSString *hash = [out description];
hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
hash = [hash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];
// hash is now a string with just the 40char hash value in it
```

this gives me a code thats = to sha1() function in php, but if i do that, i have to reset all the current users pass and mail it to them :-/

Comment: C#? Are you sure you're looking at the good technology?

Comment: A password stored in a database behind the PHP web app? Have PHP do the hashing, don't just blindly accept a hash supplied by untrusted code. Also, am I mistaken or is your salt a constant? Don't do that, that defeats a large amount of the purpose of salting the passwords in the first place (you can attempt to crack all at once instead of only one at a time)! Also, there's better choices than straight SHA1, such as PBKDF2.

Comment: thanks Kitsune, i want useres to be able to make a new password on a php site if thay forget it.... right now i cant help them... all i can do is delete the user ....